# Sign all jars and wars maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, jarsigner

How to sign all jars and wars that are generated in project when i clean and build with maven ? Is there such plugin and instruction how to use it. I found this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/usage.html while searching the internet but there is no good instruction how to use or test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>sign</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>sign</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <archiveDirectory>jars location</archiveDirectory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.jar</include>
    </includes>
    <keystore>/path/to/keystore.jks</keystore>
    <alias>...</alias>
    <storepass>...</storepass>
    <keypass>...</keypass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This code worked for me